# What is the context of "this" in this example?

Tags: javascript, this

Why do these two lines create different values for `this`?

```
<div>
  <a href="#" id= "li2" onclick="alert(this)"> a link </a> 
</div>
<p id= "p2" onclick="alert(this)"> a paragraph </p>
```

The first one alerts with the file's URI, the second one alerts with the "HTML Paragraph Element". So in other words, the second one context is the DOM element, but the first one is the main context.

I have done A LOT of research on this, and some of them are a bit over my head, so if someone knows the answer, can you dumb it down for me?

Comment: _“this first one alerts with the file's URI”_ – only because the `href` value of that link is `#`. Would the `href` be `http://example.com/` instead, you would have gotten that value.

Comment: [Javascript](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/61739776.jpg).

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging, it converts its parameter to a string, which can be confusing and not helpful.  I'd suggest `console.log()` instead, then you'd see *exactly* what `this` was.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. You explained exactly what I needed to know. I am planning to now pass 'this' to a javascipt, so I can call methods/properties on the element. thanks!!! I wish I can have more than one 'best' answer though... :) :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In inline JavaScript events, `this` is the *element* that the event was triggered on.  These are both `onclick` events, so `this` is the element you clicked on.

When you use `alert()`, it converts its parameters to a string.  When you convert an `<a>` element object to a string, you get its `href` value.  When you convert a `<p>` element to a string, you just get `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` since it doesn't have a custom `toString`.

Revalent docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/toString

Answer (score 3):

For `onclick` events, the `this` variable is bound to the DOM element being clicked. When you call `alert` on variables in javascript, it actually calls `toString()`. When `toString()` is called on an anchor tag, the `href` attribute is actually returned. When called on the paragraph tag, it does not have a built-in `toString()` method and the default one is used (the one that simply prints `[object objectName]`.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) inherits methods from HTMLElement (naturally) as well as implements [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement#Methods) of URLUtils interface. The later in its turn has method [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/toString) which returns current href property.

When you `alert` anything it casts its arguemnt to string type, e.g. calling toString method of the argument. Hence the behavior you see.

HTMLParagraphElement (`<p>`) doesn't have this properties and hence `toString` of it simply returns default string `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`.